# What is the difference between Session with totals.visits = null and Bounced Session?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am deeply confused by the difference between them.

I know totals.visits = 1 when a session has at least an interaction type event, and that a session with only a non-interaction type event will have totals.visits = 0. ** In this case, a session meant a unique combination of fullVisitorid + visitId.

I have come across definitions of Bounce online that states that a bounce is defined as a session where the entrance page = exit page. Some definition goes on further to say that the session must also have no interaction type event to be a bounce, on top of entrance page = exit page.

So, what is the difference between them?

P.S. I ask because there can be sessions with both totals.visits = 1 and totals.bounces = 1, which means a bounce is not the same as a session with null totals.visits and vice versa.

P.P.S. If a pageview is an interaction hit, how can a session have no interaction event? Is it possible to have a session without pageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a session with only the main tracker loaded (meaning pageview) and both pageview and some event tracked on the page.

Those events can be either no-interaction=1 or 0 (with 0 being the default one, meaning that this event will be counted as an interaction).

A pageview is one type of interaction, while an event is another one (but it may or may not be tracked as an interaction, depending on the setup mentioned above).

This means that every time someone visits your site, and you fire a pageview, it is treated as an interaction and later a bounce if they leave that page without any other interaction tracked upon it in the next 30 minutes (during one session). That further interaction might be a next pageview or an event.

Now, you can have a specific case in which you don't have a pageview, but you do send an event interaction. If the visitor leaves the page not going to any other page, triggers no other (interaction) event, and if that single event is set to be no-interaction=1 as well, then you definitely don't have a bounce, since there was no interaction at all tracked.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Is there any case where a session does not have a pageview? Because that is the only way a session would have no interaction hit right?

Comment: There is: when an event is fired which is of no-interaction=0 type (meaning the default type of interaction for an event). You would have an event fired, but not a pageview. That is pretty common when sending hits to GA through Measurement protocol (from the server side, not from user's frontend)

Answer (score 0):

totals.visits = null means that within the session there were no any interactions, but could be non-interaction event. Bounced session means that within 1 session there was at least 1 interaction (pageview)